# Is there a list of all compiler intrinsic function for Delphi by version?

Tags: delphi, intrinsics

As answered in other SO questions modern Delphi finally supports compiler intrinsic functions like `AtomicIncrement`.

Is there somewhere a list of which intrinsic function is introduced in what version of Delphi so I could use `{$if CompilerVersion ...}` to keep the code backward compatible (with inline asm) and cleaner for future compilers?

Comment: You could use {$IFDEF NEXTGEN} for AtomicIncrement,AtomicCmpExchange,AtomicExchange and AtomicDecrement.

Comment: @LURD Then you'd deny yourself the ability to use them on the desktop platforms, which would be a shame

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I know. I was only refering to the docs: `In a multi-platform application, atomic intrinsics can be used inside {$IFDEF} for either the AUTOREFCOUNT or NEXTGEN conditional.` [Use Atomic Instrinsics Instead of Assembly Language](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop#Use_Atomic_Instrinsics_Instead_of_Assembly_Language).

Comment: @LURD I can see that documentation. It's odd. The intrinsic atomic functions are the best choice on desktop platforms.

Comment: Each version has a list in system in *"{ Procedures and functions that need compiler magic }"* section.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I cannot find such a section, where is this?

Comment: @David - In system.pas. Actually I only verified D3-XE2. Search for "compiler magic". If you cannot find in later versions, I better delete the comment.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It's there, but it's not complete. It doesn't list all intrinsics. It only has the functions that support intrinsics. So, `AtomicIncrement` is not there because the compiler does it all inline with codegen.

Comment: @David - Ok, so it's like 'addr'. That leaves the docs as the only source I guess..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use the documentation, but I cannot vouch for its accuracy.

- XE7: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- XE6: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- XE5: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- XE4: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- XE3: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- XE2: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- XE: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- 2010: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/2010/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines
- And so on.

An as it happens, this list of intrinsics is incomplete. It doesn't have the functions that you are interested in. Which is a shame. If you are interested in knowing which version those specific functions were added, then you can surely work that out. If you want to have an official list that covers every single function, then it would appear not to exist. I guess you will have to either live without it, or create the list.

Back to the documentation, you can consider this list:

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.AtomicIncrement
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.AtomicIncrement
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.AtomicIncrement
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.AtomicIncrement
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.AtomicIncrement
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.AtomicIncrement

Look at the final two. The XE3 link has info, and the XE2 link is empty. Which suggests that this function was added in XE3. A quick test confirms that.

Given the lack of reliability of the official documentation, are you prepared to trust to it?

So, my advice is that you test this yourself. That has the benefit that you will know for sure that your code is correct.

Comment: And this incompleteness was exactly why I tried to see if anyone has attempted to create such a list. Apparently this is the best we can get from the current Embarcadero docu. NB: for Atomics I am going to use XE3, it seems to work.

Comment: If someone created such a list, would you trust it? I know I wouldn't!

Comment: Documentation is completely missing the new intrinsics that XE7 introduced like `GetTypeKind`, `IsManaged` or `HasWeakRef` and their effect.

Comment: @Stefan I've no idea what they are thinking of at Emba. My experience is that writing documentation will sometimes reveal design flaws. Releasing and then documenting just sets you up for a fall.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin This question doesn't need to be updated for more recent releases. It concerns a function added in the XE2/XE3 time frame. The links in the question suffice and one could argue are already excessive.